# Xcode looks for wrong OpenCV lib name: 2.4.dylib instead of 2.4.5.dylib

Tags: xcode, opencv, linker

This issue appeared after an upgrade from Mountain Lion to Mavericks, with no code changes in between.

I have installed OpenCV 2.4.5 using Homebrew. This isn't the latest version of OpenCV, but I have not upgraded because I had incompatibility issues when I tried before. I have a project in Xcode that built fine pre-Mavericks, but seemed to be unable to find Homebrew's opencv build after the upgrade.

The Xcode project's Header Search Paths have:
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/include
and the Library Search Paths have:
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib

The project builds fine. When I try to run it, I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_video.2.4.dylib
Referenced from: <executable path>
Reason: image not found
```

/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib has the file libopencv_video.2.4.5.dylib in it. It does have an alias libopencv_video.2.4.dylib, which points to libopencv_video.2.4.5.dylib. In the "Build Phases" of my target, under the heading "Link Binary with Libraries", I have libopencv_video.2.4.5.dylib

How can I get Xcode to link with the correct library?

Note:

I have already tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382164/xcode-cant-find-dylibs-after-switching-to-homebrew-for-opencv).

It appears I may be able to do the same thing as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554520/dyld-not-loaded-reason-image-not-found-libopencv-core-2-4-dylib?rq=1), but that looks super-clumsy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be resolved by uninstalling and re-installing the opencv formula through homebrew